# Regarding MQTT PubAck with QoS level one

Tags: android, mqtt, messagebroker, broker, android-open-accessory

In [this tutorial](http://www.infoq.com/articles/practical-mqtt-with-paho) in the section of `message options`

> By default, a new message instance is set to "At Least Once", a Quality of Service (QoS) of 1, which means the sender will deliver the message at least once and, if there's no acknowledgement of it, it will keep sending it with a duplicate flag set until an acknowledgement turns up,

does it mean that in the `setCallback listener-> onMessageArrived()` i have to check if any message arrived I have to resend the message again with duplicat flag set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it means the broker will continue to send the message to the subscriber until it gets an acknowledgment. The paho mqtt client code should handle this all for you.

The only thing you may want to do when using QOS1 is to check for duplicate messages in the onmessage callback. The best way to do this is to include a unique of in the message payload

Comment: thank you. but you said "include a unique of in the message payload" i did not get this sorry.

Comment: Typo, it should read "include a unique id in the message payload"

Comment: hi, maybe wou would like to have alook at this question also :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969454/the-callbacklistener-is-called-twice